# How to get Button in GXT

Tags: java, gwt, dialog, gxt

In my application I have a dialog box, which is not created by it's own class, but just added as a widget to the page. I need to add a listener to the button in this box, which is added to the dialogue box like this: 
`dialog.setButtons(Dialog.OKCANCEL);`
Or how to process the button cklick?

**UPD:** I use GXT 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the way to solve my problem. To handle the "ok" button click I needed to do the following:

```
 addDialog.getButtonById(Dialog.OK).addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent ce) {
                //todo
            }
        });
```